# How do I make this sticky footer stick to the bottom of the layout when the sidebar exceeds screenheight?

Tags: html, css

I have this two column layout, with a fixed width sidebar (red), expanding content area (blue) and a sticky footer (pink). Everything works as it's supposed to, except for the sticky footer.

When the sidebar is taller than the viewport, the blue content area doesn't expand to fill the remaining space. So when you scroll down, there is space below the footer (the green area in the screenshot).

[image: Demonstration]

How do I make sure that the .content-main area expands to force the footer down? (I should mention that I am trying to keep everything fluid and am aiming to support IE9+)

Jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/463vhday/5/

html

```
<div class="sidebar">
  <h1>Titel</h1>
  <a class="sidebar-link" href="">Link link 1</a>
  <a class="sidebar-link" href="">Link link 2</a>
  <a class="sidebar-link" href="">Link link 3</a>
  <a class="sidebar-link" href="">Link link 4</a>
  <a class="sidebar-link" href="">Link link 5</a>
  <a class="sidebar-link" href="">Link link 6</a>
  <a class="sidebar-link" href="">Link link 7</a>
  <a class="sidebar-link" href="">Link link 8</a>
  <a class="sidebar-link" href="">Link link 9</a>
  <a class="sidebar-link" href="">Link link 10</a>
  <a class="sidebar-link" href="">Link link 11</a>
  <a class="sidebar-link" href="">Link link 12</a>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <header class="content-header">Header</header>
  <main class="content-main">Main</main>
  <footer class="content-footer">Footer</footer>
</div>
```

css

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: green;
}

.sidebar {
  float: left;
  background: red;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 5rem;
}

.sidebar-link {
  display: block;
}

.content {
  display: table;
  background: yellow;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 5rem);
}

.content-header {
  display: table-row;
  background: purple;
  height: 1px;
}

.content-main {
  display: table-row;
  background: blue;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.content-footer {
  display: table-row;
  background: pink;
  height: 1px;
}
```

Comment: The footer is not at the botton on my PC. (Firefox 43.0.4)

Comment: So you're saying you want the footer to stick to the bottom ONLY when .sidebar exceeds window height? In that case that will require some Javascript to measure .sidebar height against window height. IF sidebar > window THEN add "sticky" class to footer. Run the code both on page load AND whenever the window resizes.

Comment: @philtune Well basically what I'm trying to achieve is equal height columns (sidebar and content), with a sticky footer and for content-main to fill all available space. I'd like to do this in css only.

Comment: So kinda like frames... I did a layout like that the other day using the native css `calc()` function. I know footer will be 60px high so I make the main container: `.main { height: calc(100%-60px); }`. The calc() function used to have performance concerns, but I've seen people use it quite a bit lately with the caution to use sparingly.

Comment: I think to create two columns with the same height without a table is a common problem in HTML/CSS. Maybe you can create a table with one row and two columns to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a lot of experimenting and investigation, I think my problem basically boils down to wanting to have an element (.Content-main) that automatically fills all available height.

Which isn't possible with just css for IE9+. It can be done with flexbox or javascript however. But that isn't an answer to my question. So the real answer is that it's impossible.